# Can anyone recommend a PDF->(rtf,doc,html) application for windows

Tags: windows, pdf, conversion

I would like an application able to convert a PDF to either doc, html or rtf.

- I don't want an online solution. <sub><sup>(I have tried a few but I think my PDF's are too large).</sup></sub>
- I don't need any OCR capability.

I have 64bit win7 so anything that works on that is preferable but any os back to win2k will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Infix PDF Editor](http://www.pdfediting.com/) from Iceni converts PDF documents to HTML or RTF, and support 64-bit systems...

It's pretty cool and unique because it doesn't break text up into small fragments and is able to reflow text properly.

Infix can be downloaded for free but the trial version will insert random 'x' characters into exported text.

To convert a document using Infix open your PDF file and select 'File > Export As...' from the menu.

Infix also supports 64-bit systems.

Answer (score 1):

We've been using Nuance PDFCreate successfully for years. They have a product, PDF Converter 6, that converts PDFs into Office documents as well:
http://www.nuance.com/imaging/pdfconverter/pdfconverter-converter.asp